# How to change the language from CSS to Booststrap framework of a repository on GitHub?

Tags: github

I know [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is a framework of CSS.

I have seen people putting their repo language like "Vue".

Is it possible that I can make my repo language as a framework like Bootstrap?

Right now, I have my `.gitattributes` files in this code:

```
*.css linguist-detectable=true
*.js linguist-detectable=false
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those [`detectable` linguist directives](https://github.com/github/linguist#detectable) only apply for supported languages, listed in [`linguist/languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)

And it does *not* include Bootstrap.
It does [include however `Vue`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L5528), which is why you have seen "Vue" as a "language" for some repository.